# How to calculate the double of digits from an integer in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop, integer

I am a beginner in Java and trying to learn. I have an integer from whom I want to calculate the double of each digit and then restore the answer in the integer. I think that I have to use the for() loop and tempvalue. I have the number 1234 and I need to get 2468.
I did this and I got 1234. Can someone find the issue, I am not very good with the index concept.

```
public class Doublevalue {
public static void main(String[] args) {
num=1234;
for(int i=0;num<0;i++) {
int tempvalue=(num%10*2)/10;
num=tempvalue;
System.out.print(num);
}}}
```

Comment: @Spectric I do not have experience in Java, that was my best try. I tried to separate each digit and double it, but it did not work.

Comment: Sorry about that. I believe my answer might be of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because doubling digits is only valid when every digit is less than 5, the solution can be just

```
num *= 2;
```

But if you want the treat each digit separately, you need to do something like this:

```
int tmp = 0;
for (int column = 1; num > 0; column *= 10) {
    tmp += (num % 10) * column * 2;
    num /= 10;
}
num = tmp;
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/3EHbc9).

You can do an in-place replacement of each digit, but the logic is a little more complicated.

Comment: Thank you, the second answer was perfect, even thought I did not understand how you used ''column''.

Comment: column is the digits column, which iterates through the powers of ten: 1, 10, 100, 1000, ...

Answer (score 0):

The code you currently provided has everything right - except for what you are doing in the loop.

In your example, you are executing `int tempvalue=(num%10*2)/10;`. I'm pretty certain that you are not sure what you are doing. What the line is doing is getting the remainder of the number when it is divided by 10, multiplying it by 2, then dividing by then. I can't seem to understand why you are doing this, so I will provide my own solution.

```
public class DoubleDigits {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DoubleDigits dd = new DoubleDigits();
        System.out.println(dd.doubleDigits(1234));
    }
    public int doubleDigits(int number) {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        String testCase = String.valueOf(number);
        for(int i = 0; i < testCase.length(); i++) {
            int digit = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(testCase.charAt(i)))*2;
            str.append(digit);
        }
        return Integer.parseInt(str.toString());
    }
    
}
```

**So what's happening**?

First, we convert the number to a String, so we can get each single character (as a number). The **for loop** will loop through every single character, and we can use a StringBuilder to append the character after it has been parsed to an int and multiplied by two.

In the above example, the program produces:

```
2468
```

When the test case is:

```
1234
```

And when the test case is:

```
9999
```

The result is:

```
18181818
```